# Self-signed certificate is not “trusted” by default?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, https

Self-signed certificate is not “trusted” by default? How can I make it trusted?

I used this tutorial for generate my `.crt` and `.key` - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: Just exactly like you'd trust me if I certify that I'm Elvis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Self-signed certificate is not “trusted” by default?

Obviously. Who would be trusted? A self-signed vertificate is self-contained ad as such does not have a master authority that is registere as trusted.

> How can I make it trusted?

Have you tried reading the documentation? WHich is sort of the requirement to ask qustions here (professional capacity, minimum knowledge).

I found this on google:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

THat has a lot of interesting topics.

And this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1914563

The title matches (Install self-signed cert like in Windows Trusted Root CA).

the general profesional advice is to - install a CA if you need it, or get a trusted certificate if that is too much work.